# Helicopter blade aerodynamic forces in rotating frame of reference

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

It is well known that helicopters use the concept of centrifugal stiffening. That is, there is a centrifugal force that acts against the motion of the blade due to the thrust and thereby reducing flapping angle $\beta$. Now, in order to use the analysis of centrifugal force, we must be in a rotating frame of reference.

Now, however, when the thrust force of a blade element is determined the velocity that is used always contains the $\Omega r$ term where $\Omega$ is the rotational velocity. If we consult wikipedia then we find $\vec{v_i} = \vec{v_r} + \vec{\Omega}\times \vec{r} $, where subscripts $_i$ and $_r$ denote inertial and rotating reference frame, respectively.

This leads me to think that the $\Omega r$ term in fig 3.4 appears since we are in an inertial frame. But, the forces resulting from fig 3.4 are used in fig 4.12 which is a rotating reference frame.

How is this possible, and where am I making a mistake?

[image: Blade section of a helicopter]

[image: Forces acting on blade element in rotating frame of reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go from inertial frame (the helicopter frame reference system) to the rotating frame (the one in the blade), via D'Alembert approach, where time derivative of momentum becomes *apparent* inertia forces. As an example,

$m \mathbf{a} = \mathbf{F} \qquad \rightarrow \qquad \mathbf{0} = - m \mathbf{a} + \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{F}^{in}+ \mathbf{F} $.

Here, what you interpret as centrifugal force in the frame rotating with the blade, it's just the opposite of the centripetal force that makes a blade rotate around the axis, if you look at it from the inertial reference frame, the one on the helicopter fuselage, here.

Comment: the unit of CF is $~\frac{[kg\,m^2]}{s^2}~$ this is not the force unit?

Comment: The elementary centrifugal force of an elementary section of the blade $dr$ is $dF_c = dM r \Omega^2 = (m dr) r \Omega^2$, where $m$ is the mass density per unit length and thus it has physical unit in the SI $kg/m$, and the elementary force has the right physical dimension, i.e. $\frac{kg}{m} \, m \, m \frac{1}{ s^2} = \frac{kg \,m}{s^2} = N$.

Comment: o.k the unit of m is $~\frac{[kg]}{m}~$

Comment: Good, if you're ok with the answer, please accept it, so that the community knows that is a satisfactory answer to your question

Comment: So basically, the lift force on the blade element is conserved when going from inertial to rotational frame of reference. The only thing that is changed is the acceleration in the respective frame. This is because the acceleration is caused by the force, and the force does essentialy not care about the reference frame. Is this true?

Comment: "Lift is the same" because it's a "real force". Only the interpretation of derivative of momentum to inertia forces changes, do to a non-inertial motion of the two reference frames used to describe the problem. It's like when you are in a car and change direction: if someone else sees it from the outside, a centripetal force pointing towards the centre of curvature that makes your direction change; what you (you're a "non-inertial observer", accelerating w.r.t. the inertial observer standing on the ground outside your car) feel inside the car, is a centrifugal force pointing outwards

Comment: Ok, and in that example the gravity (engineering approach, no space-time curvature explanation) acts as the 'lift' in my example. I.e. it remains the same for both observers. @basics

Comment: Yes, to be explicit: aerodynamic forces, weight, reactions through constraints are the same. To be precise, even the time derivative of momentum and inertia forces are the same, just different interpretations by different observers